# Deleting rows based on a condition multiple observations before

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have been struggling for a while now, and I am just missing a step. I hope you can help with this final step.

**Reprex**

```
structure(list(record_id = c(110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 
110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 110001, 110021, 110021, 110021, 
110021, 110021, 110021, 110021, 110021, 110021, 110021, 110021, 
110021, 110021), day_count = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 
2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14), previous_treatment = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), treatment = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), interruption_streak = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)), row.names = c(NA, 
-22L), groups = structure(list(record_id = c(110001, 110021), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:9, 10:22), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Explanation**

This is just an excerpt of the main dataset in which I have listed per participant per day how they were treated.

Here, you can see two study participants `record_id` 110001 and 110021

To count how many days their treatment was interrupted, i have created a count_streak function `interruption_streak`

This is a function of `treatment`: if `treatment` = 0, then start counting until `treatment` > 0.

Both `treatment` and `previous_treatment` can be 0 (no treatment) or 1,2,3 (treatment A,B,C)

However, as you can see in record_id 110001, you can't really call the first streak an interruption, as prior to day 1, he didn't receive any treatment at all `previous_treatment` = 0. Same goes for the first streak of 110021.

The second streak of 110021 is the only valid one which I would like to consider as an interruption and keep in the dataset:
at day 5, it went from `previous_treatment` = 1 to `treatment` = 0.

**Question**

I would like to delete all streaks which started with a `previous_treatment` = 0 and keep all streaks which started with a `previous_treatment` > 0.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Does this suffice?

```
df %>% group_by(record_id) %>% 
  filter(cumsum(previous_treatment) > 0)

   record_id day_count previous_treatment treatment interruption_streak
       <dbl>     <dbl>              <dbl>     <dbl>               <dbl>
 1    110021         5                  1         0                   1
 2    110021         6                  0         0                   2
 3    110021         7                  0         0                   3
 4    110021         8                  0         0                   4
 5    110021         9                  0         0                   5
 6    110021        10                  0         0                   6
 7    110021        11                  0         0                   7
 8    110021        12                  0         0                   8
 9    110021        13                  0         0                   9
10    110021        14                  0         0                  10
```